# How to swap td's of the table that are created dynamically and get the array of the text after swapping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Zepto dragswap plugin http://james2doyle.github.io/zepto-dragswap/ where in the last example the divs are swapped and the array is being populated and its working fine in Desktops but this is not supported in mobiles devices.

I read that [pep.js](https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.pep.js/) is being supported by all devices and browsers.

So can i have similar function in pep.js, Any help on this is more appreciated or if any fiddle is provided will be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use function insertBefore() or insertAfter() in Javascript.